# How to connect Draw wire encoder to Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, potentiometer, analog

Hello Stack Community,

I am new to Arduino, and I am trying to figure out how to connect a draw wire encoder to Arduino and collect data from it.

I have attached a link of the product that I currently have, which also has datasheet, incase anyone needs more information.

https://www.kuebler.com/en/products/measurement/linear-measuring-systems/product-finder/product-details/A30

I know that the encoder's output is through analog, but I am having trouble with connections as well.

To summarize, how can I connect the encoder to Arduino Uno?

Lastly, I am using the encoder to measure linear distance of linear actuators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the version with potentiometer output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQtif.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Connect the wiper to an analog input (A0 in the example), and use the analog reference voltage as "supply" voltage.

Comment: Hi Busybee, Thanks so much. It worked, well. I was able to convert analog values to digital values and then to volts. Since I am converting digital values to volt: I will have 0 digital value = 0 volts & 1023 digital value = 5 volts, I also know that 0 volts = 0 mm & 5 volts = 600 mm (based on draw wire encoder max & min range). Based on all of this how to convert volts to millimeters, any idea?

Comment: Why not simply multiply by 1000? -- Oh, BTW, you might like to mark the answer, comments with "thank you" are kind of frowned upon. ;-) This will help future visitors of this site, too, to decide which question/answer to read.